# how to not include all python dependecies while deployment?

Tags: python, heroku

I want to deploy my ml model and create app with the streamlit app.py I defined my dependencies inside `requirements.txt` file. Heroku downloads additional dependencies in `deployment` process and passes the slug size `500` MB.

Here is my dependencies:

```
numpy==1.21.2
pandas==1.4.1
pillow==9.1.0
streamlit==1.8.1
tensorboard==2.8.0
tensorflow==2.8.0
keras==2.8.0
keras-preprocessing==1.1.2
```

But Heroku downloads all the packages within python 3.9.0. How can I handle and uninstall the not required packages?

Comment: Like you want to uninstall a module that is currently listed in your requirements.txt?

Comment: What makes you think these other packages aren't required? Your dependencies (e.g. `keras`) have [their _own_ dependencies](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/requirements.txt), which in turn have _their_ dependencies... there's a whole dependency tree beyond the eight packages you list here.